# Chrome Extensions - Mass Accounts/Extensions Suspension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Today my three Chrome extensions web developer accounts have been disabled and all my 30+ extensions are all taken down without even single warning email, but got the email stating that

> "Where possible, make as much of your code visible in the package as
>   you can. If some of your app's logic is hidden and it appears to be
>   suspicious, we may remove it".

But, my extensions were containing **only 2-3 javascript files**, one is standard jquery js file, and other two are my own javascript files which have hardly 100+ lines of basic validation logic of javascript code.  I am 100% sure that those are not at all malicious or suspicious code.  I really don't know why Google has taken such ruthless action by suspending and taking down all extensions without even basic courtesy of informing to us.

I did get such complains from other friends who's accounts also got suspended and 100+ extensions are taken down.  It is definitely seem to be a mass action.

If anybody facing same issue, please share your experience and any solutions to get everything back.

Regards

===== manifest.json =====

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Extension Description",
    "icons": {"16": "img/icon-16.png", "48": "img/icon-48.png", "128": "img/icon-128.png"},
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },

    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "img/icon-48.png",
      "default_title": "Extension",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "js/common.js", "js/popup.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions": ["*://*/*", "tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "notifications"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about developing Chrome extensions, but about the policies of the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Provide here the manifest. Do you inject js?

Comment: I have updated the question with manifest.json.  You may look at it and let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: Actually, there were running fine since Feb 2014, and all of sudden they have taken down all extensions without any notice stating same reason code being suspicious.  All I did is code minifications. It should not cause any issue, because lot of other scripts are standard .js files, like jquery.js file that I have used.

Comment: You say minification isn't suspicious and your logic is completely basic validation.  I say you've minified a virus that is going to take over my computer.  The only reason jQuery would be exempt is because they are an open source project so that you can inspect the code before and after minification.

Comment: @Teepeemm, can you show me one such minified or normal javascript virus? I strongly think Javascript cannot be a virus, because it doesn't have access to any of the computer resources except web browser, but unless user download any executable code that might be virus, that itself cannot be a javascript.

Also, anybody can embed any code inside jquery and manage isnt?  There are many other ways to hide the code.  Just because one cannot understand the code doesn't mean that it is suspecious code. In fact, however the code is, anybody can inspect in browser by clicking "{}" in debugger.

Comment: This is absolutely a unwise decision from Google and I hate it.  They are failing to identify the difference between good and bad extensions, and simply taking down extensions and being unable to provide basic solution to identify the malicious stuff that they wanted to.

If anything wrong, then users would give -ve feedback and reporting to them as inappropriate and then makes sense taking some action.

The worst part is even our developer account itself removed.  If they would have given a formal warning, at least we could have found alternative ways to meet their new policies.

Comment: I’m not leet enough with Javascript to write a virus, but the advice around `eval` and its relatives comes down to `eval(“evil code”)`.  Why do you need `eval`?  Why do you need to minify your code?  You’re combining dangerous code (`eval`) with obfuscation (minifying), saying “trust me”, and wondering why Google is suspicious.  Minification makes browsing the source meaningless.  A debugger takes even more work and doesn’t necessarily follow all logical flow.  How do you expect anyone to distinguish good and bad extensions, when they can’t review your code and all its logical paths?